# Wordpress is unable to write files, despite correct file permissions

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, wordpress, file-permissions

I am unable to automatically install plugins or themes on my new wordpress setup. It gives me this screen:

[image]

I believe this is usually due to a write permission error on the wordpress directory. These are the steps I've done so far:

nginx as running under root user, with worker processes under nginx user:

```
# ps -ef | grep nginx | head
root     14197     1  0 07:46 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process nginx
nginx    14198 14197  0 07:46 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
```

PHP-FPM is running under root user, with worker processes under nginx user:

```
# ps -ef | grep php-fpm | head
root     14748     1  0 08:38 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php-fpm.conf)
nginx    14749 14748  0 08:38 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm: pool www
nginx    14750 14748  0 08:38 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm: pool www
nginx    14751 14748  0 08:38 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm: pool www
nginx    14752 14748  0 08:38 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm: pool www
...
```

The root user is part of the nginx group:

```
# groups root
root : root nginx
```

The wordpress directory is owned by nginx:nginx and also 777 (both recursively):

```
# ls -l /var/www/
total 4
drwxrwxrwx. 5 nginx nginx 4096 Feb 24 06:45 wordpress
```

But none of this solves the issue. I'm unsure on what to check next. I'm on centOS 7 minimal.

Comment: Note that Wordpress works via FTP on the filesystem, not directly.

Comment: Note that wordpress defaults to ftp if the owner of where it needs to write to is not "itself" (the webserver/php-fpm user). It is, a **terrible** idea to make your whole doc root owned-by/writable-to to the webserver user, and even more so because you've got it world writable.

Comment: @AD7six ... and you don't mention ngingx and PHP running as `root`. Having the doc root as world writeable is *tightly locked down* by comparison.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler the master process for both _always_ runs as root (in almost all production-like use cases at least), the workers are running as the user `nginx` - see the ps output if the wording the question leaves any doubts.

Comment: @AD7six Of course; I should pay more attention. How else could they open high privilege TCP ports, and launch processes as other user accounts. Oops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following line to your wp-config.php file for direct filesystem writing:

```
define('FS_METHOD','direct');
```